# Enable hover when the checkbox is not selected & disable it once the checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I'm trying to enable hover (adding '.add_link_twitter_hover' class) when the checkbox is not selected & disable it (removing the '.add_link_twitter_hover' class) once the checkbox is selected the same way Pinterest does it for Twitter/Facebook checkboxes when a user adds a pin:
[image]

I tried this, but it doesn't disable hover (doesn't remove '.add_link_twitter_hover' class) once mouse pointer is away:

```
   var hoverTwitter = "add_link_twitter_hover";
$(postTwitter + " input").click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass(hoverTwitter);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass(activePostTwitter);
});


$("label.add_link_twitter").hover(function(e) {
    if($("input.publish_to_twitter").is(":checked")) {
          $(this).removeClass(hoverTwitter);
      return;
    }
    $(this).addClass(hoverTwitter);
});
```

Any idea how to enable hover when the checkbox is not selected & disable it once the checkbox is selected? Thanks in advance!

Here's the jQuery:

```
var postTwitter = ".add_link_twitter"; 
var activePostTwitter = "active"; 
$(postTwitter + " input").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass(activePostTwitter);
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<label class="add_link_twitter">
<input type="checkbox" name="publish_to_twitter" class="publish_to_twitter"><span>Share on Twitter</span>
</label>
```

Here's the css:

```
.add_link_twitter{
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    bottom:16px;
    color: #a19486;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-color: #F0EDE8;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.active {
    border-color: #468BD0;
    color: #468BD0;
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
}

.add_link_twitter_hover
{
    color: #A19486;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-color: #C2B1A2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("label.add_link_twitter").hover(function(e) {
    if(!$("input.publish_to_twitter").is(":checked"))
          $(this).addClass(hoverTwitter);
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass(hoverTwitter);
});
```

The usual way to use the [`.hover()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is to supply *two* functions: the first is called when the mouse moves over the element in question, and the second is called when the mouse moves out.

So what I've done above is in the first function (mouseenter) I've added your class if the checkbox is not checked. In the second function (mouseleave) I just remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without any javascript at all. if you expect to always have the class "publish_to_twitter", just separate the two states with pseudoclasses:

```
.publish_to_twitter:hover{
width:50px;
}
input.publish_to_twitter:checked{
width:500px;
}
```

I added the input element in the selector to ensure that the checked style took precedence. Just make sure that for every style you set with :hover, you have an equivalent style in :checked.